# WordPress Dashboard: column sizing after adding custom taxonomies

Tags: php, css, wordpress

As seen in the below screenshot, my columns in the admin dashboard are not wrapping and are too small to fit all of the taxonomies I created for my posts. Do any of you know a simple fix, function or CSS?

[image: Column width is not wrapping]

I'm unsure if it's relevant, but here is the custom taxonomy code I added to functions.php:

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_subjects_hierarchical_taxonomy', 0 );
//create a custom taxonomy name it subjects for your posts

function create_subjects_hierarchical_taxonomy() {
// Add new taxonomy, make it hierarchical like categories
// First do the translations part for GUI

// Add volume taxonomy
  $labels = array(
    'name' => _x( 'Volumes', 'taxonomy general name' ),
    'singular_name' => _x( 'Volume', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
    'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Volumes' ),
    'all_items' => __( 'All Volumes' ),
    'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Volume' ),
    'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Volume:' ),
    'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Volume' ), 
    'update_item' => __( 'Update Volume' ),
    'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Volume' ),
    'new_item_name' => __( 'New Volume Name' ),
    'menu_name' => __( 'Volumes' ),
  );    
 
// Register the taxonomy
  register_taxonomy('volumes',array('post'), array(
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'labels' => $labels,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_in_rest' => true,
    'show_admin_column' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'volume' ),
  ));
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to add style to the admin using enqueue styles if you know how, but there as fast workaround using actions, simply add this to your functions.php file:

```
add_action( 'admin_print_styles', 'core_admin_print_styles', 200 );
function core_admin_print_styles() {
    $screen = get_current_screen();
    if ( 'edit' === $screen->base ) {
        echo <<<EOF
        <style>
            .widefat thead td, .widefat thead th {
                width: auto !important;
            }
        </style>
        EOF;
    }
}
```

This adds a style tag inline and sets the width of the columns to auto.
You can edit the width of specific columns as well by referring to the column's class or ID, for example 'volume' will probably have an ID 'taxonomy-volume' so you can use:

```
add_action( 'admin_print_styles', 'core_admin_print_styles', 200 );
    function core_admin_print_styles() {
        $screen = get_current_screen();
        if ( 'edit' === $screen->base ) {
            echo <<<EOF
            <style>
                #taxonomy-volume {
                    width: 15% !important;
                }
            </style>
            EOF;
        }
    }
```

I hope this helps.